# Why would i use ASP.NET MVC over just a plain ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If i have to develop a small CRM application, why would i choose ASP.NET MVC application over a conventional ASP.NET application ?

Thanks,

Chak.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191556/should-i-pursue-asp-net-webforms-or-asp-net-mvc

Comment: try this search, lots of similar questions: http://www.google.com/search?q=why+asp.net+mvc+webforms+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post, "ASP.net MVC Vs ASP.net Web Form"](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2008/07/09/asp-net-mvc-vs-asp-net-web-form.aspx), summarizes some of the advantages of either model:

> **Advantages of MVC Model**
>
> 1.Enable clean separation of concerns (SoC)
>   2.Enable full control over the rendered HTML.
>   3.Enable Test Driven Development (TDD) (built with TDD in mind).
>   4.SEO and REST friendly URL.
>   5.Easy integration with JavaScript frameworks.
>   6.Support third-party view engines such as NVelocity, Brail, NHaml.
>   7.No ViewState and PostBack events.
>   8.Follows the stateless nature of web.
>   9.Extensible and Pluggable framework.
>   10.Ideal platform for Web 2.0 applications.
>
> **Advantages of Web Form Model**
>
> 1.Provides RAD development.
>   2.Easy development model for heavy data-driven LOB applications.
>   3.Provides rich controls.
>   4.Familiar model for windows form developers.

The choice really depends on your level of experience. ASP.NET MVC has a somewhat steep learning curve, but the extra effort should be worth it in the end. But for small internal applications, Web forms could probably get you there faster and easier.

[Another article, "ASP.NET MVC Pro’s and Con’s"](http://www.ytechie.com/2008/10/aspnet-mvc-pros-and-cons.html).

Comment: Thanks. Crawling the article and its links gave me this URL http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2009/09/01/asp-net-mvc-what-is-it-and-should-i-use-it.aspx

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

First you might want to familiarize yourself with the MVC architecture pattern, and understand why using it can make your code better.

The short answer is that ASP.NET MVC encourages usage of said pattern.